# Is there a way to enable python virtualenv through userdata in an Amazon EC2 (Amazon Linux 2) instance?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, virtualenv

I am trying to enable virtualenv and install few pip packages. The below code doesn't enable the virtualenv. What I wanna do is Install python, pip, enable virtualenv, install boto3, seaborn, and sagemaker.

```
#!/bin/bash
yum update -y
sudo yum install python3 -y
curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python3 get-pip.py --user
pip3 install virtualenv
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
sudo pip3 install boto3
sudo pip3 install sagemaker
sudo pip3 install seaborn
```

I am passing the above code through userdata while creating an EC2 instance.

Comment: Try running the script (as a whole) manually on an instance to see where it breaks. It is most probably the `source` command that is causing the problem, since it activates a new environment and probably stops executing from the script. If so, you might be able to find a way to "pipe in" commands to run after it activates.

Comment: Can also go to instance and check user data logs at `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` if there are any errors.

Comment: `sudo pip3` — never use `sudo` with `pip` in a virtual env; `sudo` runs in a different environment so `pip` installs packages globally, not in the venv.